# не перенаправляются запросы на index.php в https apache

Tags: веб-сервер, apache2

Вот файл конфига сайта.

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName test.ru
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    ServerName test.ru

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/test.ru

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/test.ru.error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/test.ru.access.log combined

    SSLEngine on
    SSLProtocol all -SSLv2

    SSLCertificateFile    /home/cf/ssl/test.ru.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/cf/ssl/test.ru.key

    <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </FilesMatch>
    <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Directory>
    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

А вот htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php
```

мне надо чтобы все запросы направлялись на /index.php по https протоколу. но у меня не получается настроить.

Вот я пытаюсь подключиться к `/install`, по идее он должен перенаправить на /index.php запрос, но он этого не делает.

```
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to brokenheads.ru (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
> GET /install HTTP/1.1
> Host: brokenheads.ru
> User-Agent: curl/7.65.3
> Accept: */*
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
< Date: Mon, 24 Feb 2020 12:10:59 GMT
< Server: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu)
< Location: https://brokenheads.ru
< Content-Length: 286
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
< 
* Ignoring the response-body
{ [286 bytes data]
100   286  100   286    0     0   279k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  279k
* Connection #0 to host brokenheads.ru left intact
* Issue another request to this URL: 'https://brokenheads.ru/'
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:443...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to brokenheads.ru (127.0.0.1) port 443 (#1)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
} [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
} [512 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
{ [122 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):
{ [25 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
{ [1060 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS alert, unknown CA (560):
} [2 bytes data]
* SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
* Closing connection 1
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
```

Comment: Добавьте отладку. Как вы понимаете что переадресация не работает? Покажите вывод `curl -Lv -o /dev/null http://test.ru` где test.ru - это ваш сайт.

Comment: Конкретно с сайтом brokenheads точка ру, который был упомянут в вопросе, никакой проблемы с переадресаций нет. Переадресация происходит корректно, с кодом 301. Проблема может быть в том, что у содержимое страницы обрывается после заголовка. Конфигурация Apache здесь не при чем.

Comment: @sanmai есть проблема с переадресацией. вот посмотрите на вывод curl, который я добавил в вопрос.

Comment: @sanmai ой, блин. я недавно сделал dns сервер и кое-что делал и я отключил на своем компе в hosts перенаправление на мой хост. и щас был пример перенаправление на другой компьютер в сети. щас исправлю.

Comment: @sanmai всё, исправил.

Answer (score 0):

У вас стоит проверка на модуль SSL, который не включен по умолчанию. Включить можно так:

```
sudo a2enmod ssl
```

Comment: он включен. ...